# Invalid requests in dropbox with python requests

Tags: python, http, dropbox-api

[image]

I tried make request via dropbox doc, and get this:

```
urlToken = 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/token'
headers = {
                'code': input(),
                'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'client_id': '#############',
                'client_secret': '######',
                'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost'
    }
request = requests.post(urlToken, headers=headers)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"error_description": "No auth function available for given request", "error": "invalid_request"}
```

Comment: Parameters are not headers, use `response = requests.post(urlToken, data=headers)`... and maybe change the variable name to match

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`request = requests.post(urlToken, data=headers)`